# Proper way to put the database table id on HTML Table

Tags: php, html

I need to get the table id on my HTML table. Currently, I displayed the other attributes on HTML table but i diddn't put the index or the id. Where I can put it? should I put it on the 'td' tag and hide it ?

this is my code so far.

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "xx", "xxx");
 mysql_select_db('db_dev');

 $query3 = "SELECT * FROM project_entry";
 $result3 = mysql_query($query3);

  ?>


<table id="tableID">
                <tr class="data-head">
                    <td>Client Name</td>
                    <td>Phase</td>
                    <td>Payment 1</td>
                    <td>Payment 2</td>
                    <td>Payment 3</td>
                </tr>
            <?php   
                while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
                  $id = $row3[0]; //id
                  $companyname = $row3[1];
                  $client = $row3[2];
                  $package = $row3[3];
                  $payment1 = $row3[4];
                  $payment2 = $row3[5];
                  $payment3 = $row3[6];

                  echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td><b>'.$client.'</b></td>';
                  echo '<td>
                        <select class="phase" onchange="trackPhases(this.value)">
                            <option value="Design">Design</option>
                            <option value="Build-Out">Build-Out</option>
                            <option value="Launch">Launch</option>
                        </select>
                        </td>';
                  echo '<td><span class="price"><b>$' .$payment1. '</b></span>
                        <select onchange="updatePayment1_Status(this.value)">
                            <option value="Owed">Owed</option>
                            <option value="Billed">Billed</option>
                            <option value="Payed">Payed</option>
                        </select></td>';
                  echo '<td><span class="price" ><b>$' .$payment2. '</b></span>
                        <select onchange="updatePayment2_Status(this.value)">
                            <option value="Owed">Owed</option>
                            <option value="Billed">Billed</option>
                            <option value="Payed">Payed</option>
                        </select></td>';
                  echo '<td><span class="price"><b>$' .$payment3. '</b></span>
                        <select onchange="updatePayment3_Status(this.value)">
                            <option value="Owed">Owed</option>
                            <option value="Billed">Billed</option>
                            <option value="Payed">Payed</option>
                        </select></td>';
                  echo '</tr>';
                }
            ?>  
            </table>
```

the $id = $row3[0];  is the id of the table. Where I can put that? I am new on php development. please help me. and also, How I can access that when clicking every table row?

Here is the sample output.[image]

I need to do this because I am doing data updates using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Hidden field` or using get method , but i don't see your form nor your buttons, this code will add a hidden field containing value of id:

```
   <?php   

         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td><b>'.$id.'</b></td>';// HERE
         echo '<td><b>'.$client.'</b>';
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/></td>";//this line

   ?>
```

Comment: What if I will do like this: echo '<td style="display:none;"><b>'.$id.'</b></td>';  still I can access the id?

Comment: Yes you can using javascript,but i think the best solution is hidden field

Answer (score 0):

You have need to put this id in **tr** because it is row.

```
<table id="tableID">
    <tr class="data-head">
        <td>Client Name</td>
        <td>Phase</td>
        <td>Payment 1</td>
        <td>Payment 2</td>
        <td>Payment 3</td>
    </tr>
<?php 

    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
        $id = $row3[0]; //id
        $companyname = $row3[1];
        $client = $row3[2];
        $package = $row3[3];
        $payment1 = $row3[4];
        $payment2 = $row3[5];
        $payment3 = $row3[6];

        echo '<tr id='.$id.'>';

        ----------

        -----------

        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

And clicking on this row you will get the id like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#tableID tr").click(function(){
        var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(row_id);  
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many things.  Do you want to hide the ID from visibility?  If so, then simply don't show it as your current code.

If all you need the ID for updating the row, then it can be done in various ways.

1) pass the ID with your `onchange` method, assuming this is one of the value you need to update.  So your javascript methods becomes something like `onchange=trackPhases(this.value, '. $id. ')`.  This way you will also have the id of the row you are modifying.

2) if you need to know the table ID when clicked on the row, then you will need to do similar technique.  You will have to add `onclick` event on the `TR` or `TD` element, and pass the ID along in the method argument: `<TR onclick="rowclicked('.$id.')">`

Hope this helps!